# lazy load for dynamic create elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page in many places I use lazyload effect .
Plugin url  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload . 
For images I added class "lazy" and

```
  <input type="button" onclick="fn()" >
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    fn()
     $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  });

function fn(){


   var img = document.createElement('img');
   img.setAttribute('data-original','bg.jpg')
   img.className='lazy'
   document.body.appendChild(img);
}

</script>
```

But in other page I dinamic created images with class "lazy" but lazyload don't work ? How to fix ?

Comment: After you have created the new images, apply the lazyload plugin on them.

Comment: how you create dynamic image ? please add code

Answer (score 1):

check  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/5t0d31fx/2/)**

HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="fn()" value="load Image" >
```

JQUERY

```
function fn(){
  $('<img>')
    .data('original','https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2015/126th-anniversary-of-the-public-opening-of-the-eiffel-tower-4812727050567680-hp.jpg')
    .addClass('lazy')
    .appendTo('body')
  ;
  setTimeout(function(){
       $("img.lazy").lazyload(); 
  },100);      
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). This lazyloader is developed with dynamic content in mind. No need to trigger an event or to sacrifice separation of concerns by calling methods at different spots in your JS.

Simply use:

```
<input type="button" onclick="fn()" value="add image">
<img data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="lazyload" />
<script>
    function fn() {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('data-src', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/')
        img.className = 'lazyload';
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }

    fn();
</script>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/osnwer4w/3/